# svn diff: getting 'real' diffs for removed/readded files after merge

Tags: svn, svn-merge

So I have two branches, `b1` and `b2`. I have a working copy of `b1` checked out at a certain revision, `r1000`, and I've merged in some changes from `r1001` of `b2`.

I've manually edited a file `foo`, in my working copy, such that it's now identical to the `r1000` revision of `b1`. However, when I do an `svn diff`, the output is a diff against the `b2`, `r1001` revision, not the (empty) diff against `b1`, `r1000` that I would expect.

Is there a generic way to get `svn diff` to say "this is what's going to change in the repository if you check this in", or do I have to specify branches and revision numbers on the command line to get what I want?

Comment: How is this different from what you asked at the end of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14698292/62576) that makes this not a duplicate? (Also, please avoid all of the "let's call it"wording; we can usually follow along without them. Thanks.)

Comment: I asked this question first, didn't get any answers, and thought maybe I should ask a different question (which appears to have worked, at least partially). Would happily have deleted this one if that was an option.

Comment: I flagged this one for the moderators to review (with a link to the other one) and asked if there was some way to merge the two. :-)

Answer (score 0):

`svn help diff`, read this!

When you use `svn diff <FILENAME>` for modified file in Working Copy, it diffs (without additional options) against "pristine copy" of file, in your case it must be **b1/foo@1000**, not b2@1001 (BTW - when you merge, you merge branches, not single revision: from `svn help merge`, 1-st form "The optional '@REV' specifies both the peg revision of the URL and the **latest revision that will be considered  for merging**")

If you want and have clearly identify diff sources, you must to write it in command and use 3-rd form of diff

`diff OLD-URL[@OLDREV] NEW-URL[@NEWREV]`

where one of URL is file in WC, another URL - URL of file in repo (with PEG-revision, if needed)

> this is what's going to change in the repository if you check this in

"...if you **commit**" we say in SVN-world, and this is diff against BASE-revision **always**, `svn diff FILE` (this diff contain both - merge- and manual - changes, if they exist /and such mix is bad practice and anti-pattern/)