# svn revert after merge

Tags: svn, svn-merge

I've done an svn merge between two branches -- not checked in -- and now I want to "un-merge" some of the files in my working copy. Something like the following:

```
svn co svn://myserver/repo/branches/foo@1000 foo
cd foo
svn merge svn://myserver/repo/branches/foo@1000 \
          svn://myserver/repo/branches/bar@1000
```

(Note: I want to use `svn merge`, and not just copy the files from a working copy of `bar`, because (1) there are some legit merges, i.e. unrelated changes made on `foo` and `bar` to the same files, and (2) some files have been deleted in `bar` and I when I check in I want to delete them from `foo` as well.)

I want to check in most of the merged files, but some of them, I want to throw out the changes from `bar` branch and keep the existing file from `foo` branch. So I try:

```
svn revert baz/qux.quux
```

This does nothing. `qux.quux` still has the changes from `bar` branch. I try `svn status`; it's blank. I try copying over from a prestine copy of `foo` branch: the file now has the right content, but `svn diff` now shows the `bar < foo` diffs. `svn revert` again: now we've got the `bar` changes back. Let's try `svn info`:

```
Path: baz/qux.quux
Name: qux.quux
Working copy root path: /home/mydir/foo
URL: svn://myserver/repo/branches/foo/baz/qux.quux
Repository root: svn://myserver/repo
Repository UUID: [whatever]
Revision: 1000
Node Kind: file
Schedule: normal
Last Changed Author: [author of last change on bar, not foo]
Last Changed Rev: [rev of last change on bar, not foo]
Last Changed Date: [date of last change on bar, not foo]
```

So how do I get back to `foo`'s version of `qux.quux`? And how do I clear up the "bad" state information in my working copy?

I have the feeling I'm fundamentally misunderstanding `svn merge` somehow.

Comment: Overlookeed obvious errror - you **have not use** 2-URL-merge here - it's not needed and used incorrectly and considered as "merge of last resort"

Answer (score 0):

It appears you want to merge by cherry-picking, which is a [hack at best, in SVN](http://lookfirst.com/2011/04/subversion-mistake.html). You'll need to become an [svn merge](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.merge.htm) expert to pull this off. Other version control systems (hg, darcs, bzr) support this method of development `better`, but come with their own warts. So, pick your poison and get used to it.

Comment: Is that an answer, or a comment? I'd much rather be in git, but it's not my choice. (And I'd much rather not be using this branch structure, but that's not my choice either. Nor is performing this merge.)

Comment: [this](http://orestis.gr/) person is using [git-svn](http://orestis.gr/blog/2008/08/23/git-svn-tutorial/) and seems happy with it.

Comment: Not a great option thanks to the combination of some other decisions not in my control and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39742/does-git-have-anything-like-svn-propset-svnkeywords-or-pre-post-commit-hooks

Answer (score 0):

David, was using PEG-revision sensible and necessary decision? I just try to make merge as easy as possible, and ask you re-done merge from scratch with new clean Working Copy and show here **all, full real commands and output** (UUID isn't private data, URL of repo for test can be file:///).

Results of my test (merging heads and reverting single file) show expected results (you can re-check it on my test-case - repository is open)

- Repository Hello with some history: http://mayorat.ursinecorner.ru:8088/svn/Hello/
- Target branch Leichtbau-Deutsch: http://mayorat.ursinecorner.ru:8088/svn/Hello/branches/Leichtbau-Deutsch/
- Source branch branche-francaise: http://mayorat.ursinecorner.ru:8088/svn/Hello/branches/branche-francaise/

**Steps and operations**

```
>svn co http://mayorat.ursinecorner.ru:8088/svn/Hello/branches/Leichtbau-Deutsch/
A    Leichtbau-Deutsch\Hello.en.txt
A    Leichtbau-Deutsch\Hello.fr.txt
A    Leichtbau-Deutsch\Hello.de.txt
 U   Leichtbau-Deutsch
Checked out revision 37.

>cd Leichtbau-Deutsch

>svn merge http://mayorat.ursinecorner.ru:8088/svn/Hello/branches/branche-francaise/
--- Merging r26 through r37 into '.':
U    Hello.fr.txt
Conflict discovered in 'Z:/Leichtbau-Deutsch/Hello.de.txt'.
Select: (p) postpone, (df) diff-full, (e) edit,
        (mc) mine-conflict, (tc) theirs-conflict,
        (s) show all options: tc
U    Hello.de.txt
--- Recording mergeinfo for merge of r26 through r37 into '.':
 U   .

>svn status
 M      .
M       Hello.de.txt
M       Hello.fr.txt

>svn revert Hello.fr.txt
Reverted 'Hello.fr.txt'

>svn st
 M      .
M       Hello.de.txt
```

And **expected** result at the end

PS: I can repeat this test with PEG-revisions, if you want. But - I'll prefer use real revisions from corresponding branches and (unrelated to merge-revert) I'll have to perform (if memory serves me well) `svn up` (and blindly merge) to branch HEAD before be able to commit merge-set, because your `svn co svn://myserver/repo/branches/foo@1000` checkout not-HEAD revision and revision history in SVN **must be linear**