# Merging some but not all changes from one SVN branch to another

Tags: svn, svn-merge

Since my [specific](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14653002/svn-diff-getting-real-diffs-for-removed-readded-files-after-merge) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14698292/svn-revert-after-merge) just seem to produce UR DOIN IT WRONG, let me lay out the problem and see if someone can suggest a solution.

We have a trunkless SVN repository with several ordered branches -- v1, v2, etc. Changes from "lower" branches are automatically propagated to "higher" ones; not with `svn merge` but with who-knows-what, some perl scripts cobbled together by someone who doesn't work here any more, probably. When this would produce a conflict, the change doesn't get propagated; instead the developer gets an email and is supposed to fix it on the "higher" branch by hand. They usually do this, but not always.

(**Note:** Please don't lecture me on how insane this "branch" structure is. I'm well aware of that. It certainly wasn't my idea.)

We've decided (I say "we", but it certainly wasn't my idea) to abandon the "highest" branch and move the changes from that branch to the next one down. However, we know that we don't want any of the "higher" diffs for some areas of the code; others would produce conflicts which will need to be fixed by hand; others are changed only in the version number (which we want to stay at the "lower" version). Some of the changes are deletes or moves, so we can't just copy the higher-version files over the lower-version tree and call it done. And I've been stuck with the job.

So: how can I move some but not all of the changes from branch *n* to branch *n-1*?

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the revisions to merge:

```
svn merge -r fromrevision:torevision
```

So just do this revision merges, step by step and don't merge your revision you don't want to use.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not a question of wanting to skip certain revisions, it's a question of wanting to omit changes to certain files.